# Referencing fixtures from the same type in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, fixtures

In associations between different models, one can avoid setting foreign key IDs directly by using fixture names as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510195/rails-fixtures-how-do-you-set-foreign-keys/510217#510217). What about self-referencing associations, such as when using [acts_as_tree](http://github.com/erdah/acts_as_tree)? Trying this:

```
# categories.yml
forsale:
  name: For Sale
  parent_id: nil

books:
  name: Books
  parent: forsale
```

I get this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: table categories has no column named parent: INSERT INTO "categories" ("name", "parent") VALUES ('Books', 'forsale')
```

Is there any way to make one fixtures refence another in the same class without using explicit IDs?

**Update:**

Appending the class name between parentheses like for [polymorphic belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Fixtures.html) fixtures doesn't work either. Doing this:

```
books:
  name: Books
  parent: forsale (Category)
```

Produces a random `parent_id` for `books` instead of `forsale`'s ID.

Answer (score 5):

I've done this several times and can't tell why it's not working for you. The fixtures look correct as you have them (without the polymorphic `(Category)`). Does the association work in the rest of your app? What version of Rails are you using? You should have something like this in your `Category` model:

```
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category"
```

If you want to just force it to work you can set an explicit `parent_id` like this:

```
books:
  name: Books
  parent_id: <%= Fixtures.identify :forsale %>
```

but that's obviously less than ideal...

Comment: I ran into this as well, sometimes your associations aren't quit perfect.

Comment: This Q is old, I think it is [<%= ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify(:forsale) %>](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html#class-ActiveRecord::FixtureSet-label-Fixture+label+interpolation) now.