# Can I load some fixtures before others in Rails to loop through them in a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, fixtures

My Rails (4.2.11.1) application has a `User` model and a `Role` model. In my fixtures, I have a *users_roles.yml* file that I would like to populate by looping through all the fixtures in *roles.yml*, and assign them to a specific user. I'm doing this with the block below:

**users_roles.yml**

```
<% Role.all.each do |role| %>
<%= 'super_test_user' + role.name %>:
  user_id: <%= ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify(:super_test_user) %>
  role_id: <%= ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify(role.name.to_sym) %>
<% end %>
```

My issue is that when I run `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:fixtures:load`, Rails hits the *users_roles.yml* file first, and so there is nothing in the `Role` object for it to loop through. I've got hundreds of roles, so want to avoid doing this manually if possible.

Is there a way that I can force Rails to load the *roles.yml* fixtures before the *user_roles.yml* file when I call `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:fixtures:load`? I've tried the answer at [Loading Rails Fixtures in a Specific Order when Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046415/loading-rails-fixtures-in-a-specific-order-when-testing/31309658#31309658), but can't get this to work unfortunately. I've adapted this answer in the following way in my *test_helper.rb* file:

**test_helper.rb**

```
class ActiveRecord::FixtureSet
  class << self
    alias :orig_create_fixtures :create_fixtures
  end

  def self.create_fixtures f_dir, fs_names, *args
    Role.delete_all
    User.delete_all

    reset_cache

    fs_names = %w(role user) & fs_names | fs_names

    orig_create_fixtures f_dir, fs_names, *args
  end
end
```

Have I done something wrong in the above? Or is there another way I could achieve this?

EDIT: I should also add the reason I am loading fixtures in such a way is because this Rails application (let's call it 'A') is being called from another Rails application (B). As such, the test fixtures in 'A' need to be loaded into the test database before application 'B' calls it in the test environment.

Answer (score 0):

OK - so I've found a solution that's a bit hacky but it works. I'll post here in case anyone else runs into the same issue:

1. Run `rake db:test:prepare`
2. Run `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:fixtures:load FIXTURES=roles`
3. Now run `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:fixtures:load`

This ensures all the roles have been pre-loaded into the correct db table and can be referenced from the `Role` object in the join table fixture file.

I'd prefer to have this automated in the *test_helper.rb* file though. Any ideas how I could do this?