# This code is failing test in automated testing, but works in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm a new coder so this is probably something silly.  The below code is failing in my test suite but executing the same steps in the rails console gives the expected results:

aura_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class AuraTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @champion = champions(:aura)
    @aura = Aura.new description: "Lorem ipsum Aura blah", champion_id: @champion.id, stat_type_id: 1
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @aura.valid?
  end

end
```

aura.rb

```
class Aura < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :champion, optional: true
  belongs_to :stat_type
  belongs_to :affinity, optional: true
  belongs_to :location_group, optional: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :champion_id, presence: true
end
```

champions.rb

```
class Champion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :faction
  belongs_to :affinity
  belongs_to :rarity
  belongs_to :champion_type
  has_one :aura, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

fixtures:
champions.yml

```
  name: AuraChamp
  faction: one
  affinity: one
  rarity: one
  champion_type: one
```

When I run similar code in the rails console:

```
>> @champion = Champion.first
  Champion Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "champions".* FROM "champions" ORDER BY "champions"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Champion id: 1, name: "", faction_id: 1, affinity_id: 1, rarity_id: 1, champion_type_id: 1, created_at: "2019-07-19 23:50:18", updated_at: "2019-07-19 23:50:18">
>> @aura = Aura.new description: "Lorem ipsum Aura blah", champion_id: @champion.id, stat_type_id: 1
=> #<Aura id: nil, name: nil, description: "Lorem ipsum Aura blah", champion_id: 1, stat_type_id: 1, affinity_id: nil, location_group_id: nil, increase: nil, is_percent: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> @aura.valid?
  StatType Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "stat_types".* FROM "stat_types" WHERE "stat_types"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> true
```

I'm getting the following results when tests run

```
FAIL["test_should_be_valid", AuraTest, 0.5133701380000275]
 test_should_be_valid#AuraTest (0.51s)
        Expected false to be truthy.
        test/models/aura_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:AuraTest>'
```

Comment: I don't really know much about rails or how it's fixtures work, but could you add an `id` to your `champions` fixture? Or maybe name that fixture? It seems related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/510195/4948732). Also, I believe that `Champion.first` will not be the same as `champions(:aura)`, since one is getting the record from the database and the other is using your fixture.

Comment: Use debugger to see what errors are present for `@aura` in your test, so `@aura.errors.full_messages` and you will get the answer what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model:

```rb
class Aura < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :champion, optional: true
  belongs_to :stat_type
  belongs_to :affinity, optional: true
  belongs_to :location_group, optional: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :champion_id, presence: true  //<= Notice  this validation here
end
```

You have validation for `champion_id` which means your record will not be valid untill you provide a value for `champion_id`

Now looking at your fixture :

```
name: AuraChamp
  faction: one
  affinity: one
  rarity: one
  champion_type: one
```

You don't have `id` which your are accessing here as `@champion.id`

```rb
def setup
    @champion = champions(:aura)
    @aura = Aura.new description: "Lorem ipsum Aura blah", champion_id: @champion.id, stat_type_id: 1
end
```

> Your rails console steps are passing because when record is saved to
>   database it automatically gets a unique id

**Try to change your fixture like this:**

```
name: AuraChamp
  id: 1
  faction: one
  affinity: one
  rarity: one
  champion_type: one
```

Comment: Solved it.  The above isn't the exact answer, but it combined with the comment about using the debugger on `@aura.errors.full_messages`, got me to the answer.  The issue was that there is another related object `stat_type` that didn't have its id set in its fixtures.  So I either needed to establish it as a new instance of that object or add the appropriate `id:` to its fixtures.